# Fetch data from database to android list view

Tags: android, mysql

Im creating an android app where in im going to fetch datas such as image and text from mysql database. I have a problem with it. When i run the program, nothing was display in my listview.

Here's my City.java

```
public class City extends ActionBarActivity {

String myJSON;
 ImageView image;
TextView name,id,description;
private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
public static final String TAG_ID = "place_id";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "place_name";
public static final String TAG_ADD ="description";
//public static final String TAG_PIC ="place_icture";
JSONArray cities = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> CitiesList;
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.citylayout);
    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id);
    description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CitiesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    getData();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(City.this, "Opening", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String info1 = (String) map.get("place_id");
            String info2 = (String) map.get("place_name");
            String info3 = (String) map.get("description");
           //String info4 = (String) map.get("place_picture");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("info1", info1);
            myIntent.putExtra("info2", info2);
            myIntent.putExtra("info3", info3);
           //myIntent.putExtra("info4", info4);


            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });


}

protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<cities.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = cities.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);
            //String picture = c.getString(TAG_PIC);
            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String, String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);
            //persons.put(TAG_PIC,picture);
            CitiesList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                City.this, CitiesList, R.layout.city,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id,R.id.name, R.id.description}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://iguideph-001-site1.btempurl.com/city_info.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest debugging your code to see where it is breaking

Comment: When i run it theres no results and no error as well. Please help me. Im having a hard time with this.

Comment: There are too many unknowns and no obvious errors. You would have to set a breakpoint and debug and track the issue down.

Comment: Thanks sir for the suggestion. I followed it and discovered that theres a typo error in my code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That is great to hear :) Good luck!

Comment: Sir, if you dont mind. I was getting an error 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64' when trying to decode my image url. how can i resolved it ?

Comment: Can you paste that line of code please?

Comment: byte[] ba2 = Base64.decode(picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba2, 0, ba2.length);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);

Comment: here's my json : http://iguideph-001-site1.btempurl.com/city_info.php . is there anything wrong? Thanks for your help sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change:

```
public static final String TAG_PIC ="place_icture";
```

to

```
public static final String TAG_PIC ="place_picture";
```

in the declaration.

and

```
persons.put(TAG_PIC,picture);
```

to

```
persons.put(TAG_PIC,String.valueOf(d));
```

in `showList()`

Hope this helps!